# Why my string does not match my regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, regular-language

can somebody tell me why the string below:

```
ASLTHODSERV001.ABCDE.FGHI.CONTOSO.COM
```

does not match the following pattern:

```
"^\w{6}(?!AADS|ADC|AMOM|ASERV|SMOM|SYSMS)\d{3}.ABCDE.FGHI.CONTOSO.COM"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add extra `\w{5}` after the negative lookahead so that it would match the 5 word characters which exists before 3 digits.

```
^\w{6}(?!AADS|ADC|AMOM|ASERV|SMOM|SYSMS)\w{5}\d{3}\.ABCDE\.FGHI\.CONTOSO\.COM
```

or

```
^\w{6}(?!AADS|ADC|AMOM|ASERV|SMOM|SYSMS)[A-Z]*\d{3}\.ABCDE\.FGHI\.CONTOSO\.COM
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xG7gS5/1)

Comment: great but the problem is , it wont always be a 5. I could be passing a:
ASLTHOSERV001.ABCDE.FGHI.CONTOSO.COM

Comment: check my update.. Use `[A-Z]*` to match zero or more uppercase letters or `.*?` or `\w*?`

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
"^\w{6}(?!AADS|ADC|AMOM|ASERV|SMOM|SYSMS)
   ^^^^^--- 6 characters

ASLTHODSERV001.ABCDE.FGHI.CONTOSO.COM 
123456
```

which leaves `DSERV...`, which is **NOT** present in the rest of your regex. The closest would be `ASERV`, but you have `DSERV`, so nothing can match.